# How to get AWS metdata on node creation using client-go

Tags: kubernetes, kops, aws-sdk-go, client-go

I'm working on writing custom controller for our kubernetes cluster and that'll listen to node events and perform some operation on the node.I'm using kubernetes client-go library and able to capture kubernetes events whenever a node is attached or removed from the cluster. But is it possible to get AWS instance details of kubernetes node that has been created like instance id, tags etc ? Thanks in advance.

PS: I have installed the kubernetes cluster using kops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On receiving the event for node creation, it's object ***object***'s attribute Name ***object.Name*** has the private dns of the aws instance that was created. Using the private dns of the instance, we could query for instance-id using aws-sdk-go

```
hostName := object.Name
sess := session.Must(session.NewSessionWithOptions(session.Options{
    SharedConfigState: session.SharedConfigEnable,
}))

// Create new EC2 client
ec2Svc := ec2.New(sess)
var instanceId string
params := &ec2.DescribeInstancesInput{
Filters: []*ec2.Filter{
                {
                        Name:   aws.String("private-dns-name"),
                        Values: []*string{aws.String(hostName)},
                },
        },
}
// Call to get detailed information on each instance
result, err := ec2Svc.DescribeInstances(params)
if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("there was an error listing instances in", err.Error())
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
}
for idx, res := range result.Reservations {
        fmt.Println("  > Reservation Id", *res.ReservationId, " Num Instances: ", len(res.Instances))
        for _, inst := range result.Reservations[idx].Instances {
                // result[idx].SetDisableApiTermination(true);
                instanceId = *inst.InstanceId
                fmt.Println("    - Instance ID: ", *inst.InstanceId)
                break // Only one instance will match the private dns
        }
}
```

With the instance id, we could perform any operations on the ec2 instance using aws-sdk-go API's.

Answer (score 1):

On a Kubernetes node in AWS, you'll have some things populated as part of the node labels and various other parts of the node's metadata:

```
kubectl get nodes -o json | jq '.items[].metadata.labels'

{
  "beta.kubernetes.io/arch": "amd64",
  "beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type": "c5.large",
  "beta.kubernetes.io/os": "linux",
  "failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region": "us-east-1",
  "failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone": "us-east-1b",
  "kubernetes.io/hostname": "<hostname>",
  "kubernetes.io/role": "master",
  "manufacturer": "amazon_ec2",
  "node-role.kubernetes.io/master": "",
  "operatingsystem": "centos",
  "tier": "production",
  "virtual": "kvm"
}
```

The node information is in `client-go` in the [node package here](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/kubernetes/typed/core/v1/node.go) using the `Get` method. Here's an example:

```
  client := kubernetes.NewForConfigOrDie(config)

  list, err := client.CoreV1().Nodes().List(metav1.ListOptions{})
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "error listing nodes: %v", err)
    os.Exit(1)
  }

  for _, node := range list.Items {
    fmt.Printf("Node: %s\n", node.Name)
    node, err := client.CoreV1().Nodes().Get(node.Name, metav1.GetOptions{})
    if err != nil {
      fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "error getting node: %v", err)
      os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Println(node)
  }
```

*However* this is really probably not the way you want to go about it. If you're running this on a kops cluster in AWS, the node your workload is running on already has access to the AWS API and also the [IAM role](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/faqs/) needed to query node data.

With that in mind, please consider using the [AWS Go SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go) instead. You can query EC2 quite easily, here's an [adapted example](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/go/example_code/ec2/describing_instances.go):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/ec2"
)

func main() {
    // Load session from shared config
    sess := session.Must(session.NewSessionWithOptions(session.Options{
        SharedConfigState: session.SharedConfigEnable,
    }))

    // Create new EC2 client
    ec2Svc := ec2.New(sess)

    // Call to get detailed information on each instance
    result, err := ec2Svc.DescribeInstances(nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Success", result)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) It helped me to a extent. Using kubernetes metadata I was not able to retrieve ec2 metadata.. And just going by aws-sdk-go, I won't be able to map the corresponding node. Filtering the instances using private DNS (from hostname of node) gave the instance id through which I'm able to perform other operations